# change the name default console from "<" to R< in r

Tags: r, console

I want to change the name of the command to start commands in the console section from <  to  R<

Comment: Do you mean from `>` to `R>` ?

Comment: @akrun - it might be relevant but it's defintiely not a 'duplicate' since it's not on stackoverflow...

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean you want to change it from

```
>
```

to

```
R>
```

the following should do it for you

```
options(prompt = "R> ")
```

The 'prompt' value in options defines the prompt for signifying waiting on a new command.

If you also want to modify what it shows when a new line has been hit but you a command hasn't been fully completed you could modify the 'continue' option like such:

```
options(continue = "R+ ")
```

Making both of those changes will result in a console that looks something like this:

```
R> for(i in 1:4){
R+     print(i)
R+ }
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
R>
```